# webapp start fail on tomcat6

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jdbc, centos

I am trying to deploy a webapp on tomcat6/CentOS5

I did the configuration, but when I try to start the webapp it fails
so as the guys over here said a made some modification in longing system and here is the new logs.

The last lines of `/usr/local/tomcat/logs/catalina.out` are:

```
------------- org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: start: Starting web application at '/'
------------- org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.ambraproject.configuration.WebAppListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
        at org.ambraproject.configuration.WebAppListener.<clinit>(WebAppListener.java:40)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1276)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:625)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doGet(HTMLManagerServlet.java:136)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:194)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:563)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
            ... 30 more
------------- org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
    SEVERE: Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
    Mar 2, 2013 5:46:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
```

---

and my webxml  file from /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">

  <display-name>Ambra</display-name>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/propertyConfigurer.xml /WEB-INF/countryList.xml /WEB-INF/profaneWords.xml /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>log4j.properties</param-value>
  </context-param>



  <resource-ref>
    <description>Main Ambra Database</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/AmbraDS</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>

  <resource-env-ref>
    <description>File Store for Ambra</description>
    <resource-env-ref-name>ambra/FileStore</resource-env-ref-name>
    <resource-env-ref-type>org.ambraproject.filestore.FileStoreService</resource-env-ref-type>
  </resource-env-ref>

  <filter>
    <description>Filter out any request that matches regexp</description>
    <filter-name>SinkHoleFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.ambraproject.web.GatekeeperFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>regexp</param-name>
      <param-value>.*\.ftl$</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>MultipleRequestFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.ambraproject.web.MultipleRequestFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>includePattern_fetchArticle</param-name>
      <param-value>.*\/article\/info.*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>includePattern_browseIssue</param-name>
      <param-value>.*browseIssue\.action.*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>includePattern_browseVolume</param-name>
      <param-value>.*browseVolume\.action.*</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>

  <filter>
    <description>Sets the virtual journal context.
Should be 1st in the chain as other Filters, e.g. caching, may rely on the journal context.</description>
    <filter-name>VirtualJournalContextFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.ambraproject.web.VirtualJournalContextFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter>
    <description>Should immediately follow VirtualJournalContext in Filter chain.
If a virtual journal context is set, check to see if requested resource has a virtual journal override.
If so, wrap request with virtual journal override values in FilterChain.</description>
    <filter-name>VirtualJournalMappingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.ambraproject.web.VirtualJournalMappingFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>DummySSOFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.ambraproject.web.DummySSOFilter</filter-class>
    <!-- uncomment these if you want to be logged in by default when you start the server
    <init-param>
      <param-name>auth.id</param-name>
      <param-value>foo</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>email</param-name>
      <param-value>foobar@b.com</param-value>
    </init-param>
    -->
    <init-param>
      <param-name>casUrl</param-name>
      <param-value>https://localhost:7443/cas/</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>wrapRequest</param-name>
      <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>CAS Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.ambraproject.service.cas.client.filter.CASFilterWrapper</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>edu.yale.its.tp.cas.client.filter.loginUrl</param-name>
      <param-value>https://localhost:7443/cas/login</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>edu.yale.its.tp.cas.client.filter.validateUrl</param-name>
      <param-value>https://localhost:7443/cas/proxyValidate</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>edu.yale.its.tp.cas.client.filter.serverName</param-name>
      <param-value>localhost:8080</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>edu.yale.its.tp.cas.client.filter.wrapRequest</param-name>
      <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>gzip</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.mortbay.servlet.GzipFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>minGzipSize</param-name>
      <param-value>100</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>mimeTypes</param-name>
      <param-value>text/html,text/plain,text/css,text/javascript,application/xml,application/atom+xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>journalStaticResources</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.ambraproject.web.JournalStaticResourceFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <!--
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
    -->
    <filter-class>org.ambraproject.struts2.AmbraStruts2Dispatcher</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>packages</param-name>
      <param-value>struts</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>

  <!--
  <filter>
    <filter-name>DebuggingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.ambraproject.web.DebuggingFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  -->


  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SinkHoleFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MultipleRequestFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>VirtualJournalContextFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>VirtualJournalMappingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>DummySSOFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CAS Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/annotation/secure/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CAS Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/user/secure/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CAS Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/rate/secure/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CAS Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>gzip</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>journalStaticResources</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>

  <!--
  <filter-mapping >
    <filter-name>DebuggingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>
-->

    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


  <!-- The configuration WebAppListener to pull in the configuration stuff automatically. -->
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.ambraproject.configuration.WebAppListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <!-- to hook in the spring container -->
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <!-- to hook in the scope management system that provides scopes like session, request for Servlet 2.4 and Spring 2.0 above  -->
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <!-- Count the number of active sessions and make it available.   -->
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.ambraproject.web.SessionCounter</listener-class>
  </listener>



  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/static/pageNotFound.action</location>
  </error-page>

  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>1440</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Not enough information here.  What you are seeing is the symptoms of the problem.  Tomcat is trying to undeploy the app and while doing so, complains that the app is leaking memory by creating a thread.  Why did it try to undeploy?  Because it failed during deployment.  You did not include any log messages related to the deployment error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the Apache commons-logging jar file in your classpath?  It seems to be a class that is a part of commons-logging that you are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Create `WEB-INF/classes/logging.properties` in the war file, with the following content:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

That will help you find the real problem of the `Error listnerStart` line. I've used this before and found `ClassNotFound` errors and other causes.

More information [here](http://mythinkpond.wordpress.com/2011/07/01/tomcat-6-infamous-severe-error-listenerstart-message-how-to-debug-this-error/).

Comment: tanks i did as u said, but still usr/local/tomcat/logs/catalina.out is gives the same outPut

Comment: Then you will need to do as Brandon said in the comment, and provide more information. Post your `web.xml`, and more information about your webapp, or if there are other logs before the first SEVERE.

Comment: As Michael said, you are missing commons-logging